# parse form_for/form_tag to get the url or controller/action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing

I want to parse form_for and form_tag statements in erb files to determine which urls they post to or which controller/action will be called.

For example, given a ".html.erb" file, I want to get all "<%= form_for %>" tags out, somehow parse it, and get to know which exact controller/action pair will be called after I click to submit this form. For instance, the following file, https://github.com/jcs/lobsters/blob/master/app/views/stories/new.html.erb
line 7, "<%= form_for @story do |f| %>", can I determine which controller/action pair it will be mapped to by running some line of code? just like "routes.recognize_path 'form_for @story do |f|'" such kind of thing?

form_tag
form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)

form_for
form_for(record, options = {}, &block)

Looks like I need to somehow get the url_for_options and options object out and get the url element out. Is there any easy way to do it or is there any existing tools that can achieve such functions? Does rails have any built-in functions for such thing?

Comment: the `log ` can give you

Comment: @RajarshiDas thanks! Do you mean if I click on these form links the console log will output the corresponding controller/actions?

Comment: development.log or production.log

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to achieve. could you please alter your question to include a scenario with context where what you are asking for makes sense?

Comment: @phoet thanks! I added some more info, does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i understand your question correctly, especially the part about parsing your views etc, but you can generate urls by calling `url_for`.

for example in your rails console you can do the following:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
default_url_options[:host] = "localhost"
url_for @user # => "http://localhost/users/1"
```

Comment: May I ask where "@user" comes from and what the value of @user is?

Comment: it's just another example. in your code, you had `@story` passed to `form_for`